# Not able to change datatype of Additional Column in Copy Activity - Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am facing very simple problem of not able to change the datatype of additional column in copy activity in ADF pipeline from String to Datetime

[image: Screenshot of copy activity]

I am trying to change source datatype for additional column in mapping using JSON but still it doesn't work with polybase cmd

[image]

When I run my pipeline it gives same error

[image]

Is it not possible to change datatype of additional column, by default it takes string only

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic columns return string.

Try to put the value [Ex. utcnow()] in the dynamic content of query and cast it to the required target datatype.

Otherwise you can use data-flow-derived-column :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column

Answer (score 0):

Since your source is a query, you can choose to bring current date in source SQL query itself in the desired format rather than adding it in the additional column.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use formatDateTime as shown below and define the desired Date format:

[image]

Here since format given is ‘yyyy-dd-MM’, the result will look as below:

[image]

**Note**: The output here will be of *string* format only as in Copy activity we could not cast data type as of the date.
We could either create current date in the Source sql query or use above way so that the data would load into the sink in expected format.